# Workflow Engine Suggestion

Tags: performance, workflow, bpel, bpmn

I need a workflow engine, with best performance. Such as handling more than 300k transaction per hour.

It should have easy interface and robust. Defining business flows by bpel or bpmn is appreciated but not required.

Answer (score 3):

I like to suggest some opensource BPEL alternatives.

1. [WSO2 BPS](http://wso2.com/products/business-process-server/)
2. [Apache ODE](http://ode.apache.org/)

Both of above should able handle the performance requirements that you have mentioned.
You may have to use in-memory BPEL processes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try jBPM5? For your requirements I can deduct that you have only automatic/short-running processes right? You can create using jBPM5 custom and pluggeable boxes where you can define external interactions that can be used inside your flows. visit jbpm.org for more information.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to have a look at [Activiti](http://www.activiti.org) engine.
It's a lightweight library with a good API under a Apache license.